# How to make page autoscroll to DIV onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quicklaunch (*bookmark list* if you'd like) which will send the user to different pages with lots of text. So I want them to be sent to the specific paragraph.

Is it possible to make a page autoscroll to a specific DIV onload and how?
I'll live without the animation. If it can just go to it directly that'll make my day. Like when you have an `<a href="#SomeId">` tag and when you click that anchor it sends you to that div.

Edit: If the user bookmarks the top paragraph, an ID isn't saved for the link. So in that case I just want it to go to the where the content div starts. How is this possible?

Comment: Simply add id in the paragraph `<p id="myid"></p>`, and make URL with `#myid`.

Comment: How are you opening the new page? Have you tried with "yoururl#someid" giving the id of the div in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.location.hash = "myDiv";
```

This will change the hash to `myDiv` (and scroll to the element whose `id` attribute is equal to the hash).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/QDNeQ/).